# Why my bot showing info only in terminal?

Tags: javascript, discord

I want to display player count on my Discord server like that:

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SuMo.png)

If I use the `!players` command

```
const Gamedig = require('gamedig');

Gamedig.query({
    type: 'samp',
    host: '91.121.87.14',
    port: 9180
}).then((state) => {
    console.log(state);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Server is offline");
});
```

I run my Discord bot with this code and it's showing me the info but only in the terminal I want like that:

[Output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZCCO.png)

I just want my bot to display player count like above in the pic

Comment: The answer to "Why" is "Because you haven't written code that would post the server status anywhere else than the console".

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your code to post a message in Discord.
Try [Discord Webhooks](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks).

Answer (score 0):

You use the lib "gamedig" which provides the following function:

> node-GameDig is a game server query library, capable of querying for the status of almost any game or voice server.
> (https://github.com/sonicsnes/node-gamedig)

Currently, the data read from "gamedig" is only output via the console.

In order to display the data in Discord like on your first screenshot, you have to talk to the Discord API (https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro)

Answer (score 0):

The question is: "Why my bot showing info only in terminal?"
The answer is: Because you asked it only to `console.log`

I don't know your lib, but it seems it only returns data from the server.
Use discord.js to make a discord bot  https://discord.js.org/#/

Hope it helped